# Javascript copy date + one year

Tags: javascript, forms

I don't know why i can't find an answer to this but its been over 2 hours of searching now and I'm about ready to break something.

All i need to do is copy a user entered date and add one year:

```
<input id='r_start' name='r_start' type='date' value='' />
<input id='r_end' name='r_end' type='date' value='' />
```

so when r_start is edited, r_end is automatically updated to plus one year,

this should not be difficult right? Been a long day!

-> Calendar year please

Comment: It is indeed very difficult because the length of a year varies. Edit your question to specify the type of year (astronomical year or calendar year?) wanted, and the precision required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GdcPS/18/)

**HTML**

```
<input id='r_start' name='r_start' value='' type='date'/>
<input id='r_end' name='r_end' value='' type='date' />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#r_start').on('change',function(){
        var d = new Date($(this).val());
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+13);
        var a = ((d.getMonth()) < 10) ? '0'+(d.getMonth()) : (d.getMonth());
        var b = (d.getDate() < 10) ? '0'+d.getDate() : d.getDate();
        d = d.getFullYear()+'-'+a+'-'+b;
        $('#r_end').val(d);
    });
});
```

Comment: I had to change .on('change', to .bind('change', and for some reason need to add d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+13); instead of 12 - but it works, thank you

Comment: Yes, that's because `getMonth()` starts month numbers from 0. I missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WNNe2/1/)**

Just add 12 months to the date:

```
 var yourDate = new Date();
 yourDate.setMonth(yourDate.getMonth()+12);
```

Comment: ok, but how am i feeding in the first date? I've tried: yourDate = new Date(document.getElementById('r_start').value); AND yourDate = document.getElementById('r_start').value;